# How do you use pentadactyl with firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I recently installed the latest Pentadactyl nightly (as of 2-Nov-12) on FF 16.0.2, on OS X Mountain Lion.  I am slowly coming to grips with the extensive options, however I cannot figure out how to use FireBug 1.10.6, which I had installed previously and was using.

I searched around a bit and found some bug reports which mentioned that installing AceBug would magically "fix" any issues, but I tried AceBug 1.10.0 and still no dice - how do I see and interact with the FireBug console, etc?

I found a Pentadactyl plugin called firebug-pentadactyl on Github that claims to add FireBug support to Pentadactyl but when I type:

```
:firebug console
```

...nothing happens.  Who here is successfully using Pentadactyl with FireBug and can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Ahhh...it seems to start working once I run

`:toolbarshow Navigation Toolbar`

...and then click on the FireBug button to start it once.  Then from any tab I can use the ":firebug" commands to utilize the add-on with Pentadactyl keyboard shortcuts.  But it doesn't seem to work until I have shown the toolbar and manually started FireBug once.

Does anybody have a way around this?  Thanks

Comment: Another update - this problem was due to the fact that the F12 "Open Firebug panel" hotkey is by default mapped to "Volume Up".  If you hold Fn and press F12, the Dashboard is shown.  I fixed this by going to System Preferences > Mission Control, and remapping the Dashboard shortcut to a different function key.  Hopefully this can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, answered in the comments, but will repeat here:

This problem was due to the fact that the F12 "Open Firebug panel" hotkey is by default mapped to "Volume Up". If you hold Fn and press F12, the Dashboard is shown. I fixed this by going to System Preferences > Mission Control, and remapping the Dashboard shortcut to a different function key.  Probably wouldn't be encountered by a Linux or Windows user.